# How to prevent the child from parent animation in css?

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation

```css
#path1{
position: absolute;
width:250px;
height:250px;
border-radius:100%;
text-align: center;
top:25%;
left:10%;
border:1px solid grey;
animation: round 3s infinite linear;
}
#path1:after{
  content:"";
position: absolute;
width:250px;
height:250px;
border-radius:100%;
text-align: center;
top:25%;
left:10%;
animation: round 3s infinite linear;
}
#earth{
position:relative;
width:40px;
height:40px;
background-color:orange;
border-radius:100%;
text-align: center;
box-shadow:1px 1px 30px grey;
margin-left:10px;
}
@keyframes round {
 from{
 transform: rotate(0deg);
         
 }
 to {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
             
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="path1">
<p id="earth"></p>
<p>static text</p>
</div>
```

I have one Css animation code [See my Fiddle here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/prasanth1036/9o5oLbzj/4/).
Parent div are rotate.But the child also affect the css.I also tried with `:after` and `:before`  css function but its not work.please How to prevent child div from parent animation.Thanks in advance

Comment: Use 'reverse' for the text paragraph

Comment: Just in case you weren't able to figure it out based on that answer. Here is a fiddle for you - https://fiddle.jshell.net/9o5oLbzj/6/ (I have added an inline comment to explain why the `transform-origin` is set that way)